# SQL query returns empty result in PHP - same query returns result in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, encoding, character-encoding

I have a webpage which executes several MySQL queries using PHP and returns the results.
One query contains a special character - Î - as in ...`WHERE region="Île-de-France"`... When executed by PHP this query executes successfully but returns an empty result set, when it should return a result. In an attempt to debug I used echo on the $sql variable holding the sql query (just before it is executed) and copied the result into PHPMyAdmin. Here the same query returned the result I was expecting.

Why is this query returning nothing when executed by PHP?

Things I have tried based on information I didn't particularly understand:

I used `$sql=$db->real_escape_string($sql)` before executing the query. This changed the relevant portion of $sql to `...WHERE region=\"Île-de-France\"`... and resulted in an error upon execution of the query.

I also tried `if($state){$sql=$sql." AND state ='".$db->real_escape_string($state)."'";}`. The query now executed successfully but yielded no results.

Comment: do you mean `WHERE region='Île-de-France'` <-- single quotes?

Comment: Nope. I'm using double quotes here. Works the rest of the time.

Comment: And changing it makes no difference.

Comment: you should not use `real_escape_string` on the sql it should be used on the values you send like on `Île-de-France`

Comment: I tried that as well - see edit for the exact code I used.  The query was successful but returned an empty result set.

Comment: that query looks fine. can you check what is in the `$sql` variable just before executing the query?

Comment: $sql is now WHERE ... AND state ='Île-de-France' .... No results are returned when executed by PHP. But again, copying and pasting into PHPMyAdmin gives the single result I am expecting.

Comment: there seems to be no error in this part. the error may be in some other part of the sql. try copying the entire sql command as you get from php and run in PHPMyAdmin.

Comment: That's what I did. I echoed $sql right before executing, copied and pasted to PHPMyAdmin. I am most puzzled.

Comment: Sounds like the database connection you are using has a different character encoding, I would check the default encoding and or try setting it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @Shaun. Solved with $db->set_charset("utf8");
Do you want to make that into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Why's this tagged with phpMyAdmin? Are you also having trouble searching from within phpMyAdmin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the database connection you are using has a different character encoding, I would check the default encoding and or try setting it explicitly.